# EmEditorで固定長のデータを読み込む際に特定の空欄列を削除してから読み込むには？

Tags: emeditor

以前EmEditorで固定長(230行）のテキストデータを特定の行毎に区切って読み込む方法を教えていただきました。
今回は同じデータであらかじめ複数の空欄列を削除して、残りのデータの存在する列だけ読み込む方法をお教え下さい。以下、頂戴したコードを引用します。

ここで、以下のデータのうちイタリックボールドが空欄です。

C4,C8,C,C2,C2,C9,C12,C,***C7***,C,***C***,***C2***,***C7***,C,C9,C,C9,C,C9,***C4***,C,C8,C,***C***,C9,***C***,C9,***C2***,***C4***,C,C9,***C2***,***C4***,***C***,***C6***,***C3***,***C***,***C9***,***C***,***C9***,C,C,***C***,***C***,***C***,***C***,C20,***C***,***C30***

これら空欄の列を24カ所を削除してから読み込みたいです。ちなみにdocument.Convert以下のコードの最後は20,1となっておりますが、これは20,1,30の間違いでした。30が入って合計230バイトです。

[image: 高度に開く]

```
document.ConvertCsv(1,eeCsvHalfWidth | eeCsvDiscardUndo,"4,8,1,2,2,9,12,1,7,1,1,2,7,1,9,1,9,1,9,4,1,8,1,1,9,1,9,2,4,1,9,2,4,1,6,3,1,9,1,9,1,1,1,1,1,1,20,1");
```

Comment: 解凍ありがとうございました。最後に追加の仕方ですが

Answer (score 2):

CSVに変換したあと、[CSV] メニューの [列の管理] コマンドを選択して、不要な列を削除して OK をクリックします。

また、この操作の前後に、[マクロ] メニューの [記録/停止] を選択して、この操作をマクロに記録すれば、次のような JavaScript マクロとして保存できます。

```
document.RearrangeColumns("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,14,15, ...");
```

この行を ConvertCsv.jsee の最後に追加します。

Comment: document.ConvertCsv(1,eeCsvHalfWidth | eeCsvDiscardUndo,"4,8,1,2,2,9,12,1,7,1,1,2,7,1,9,1,9,1,9,4,1,8,1,1,9,1,9,2,4,1,9,2,4,1,6,3,1,9,1,9,1,1,1,1,1,1,20,1");
document.RearrangeColumns("1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,14,15, ...");がただしい書き方でしょうか？最後に書くの最後がコマンドをセミコロンでわけるのか、コマンドをネストするかわからないためお教え下さい。

Comment: それで正しいです

Comment: ご確認ありがとうございました。